# WP "Call to Action" plugin causes JS errors

Tags: wordpress

I found that I am getting js errors when I have the Call to Action wordpress plugin enabled.
My hunch is that it is because CTA also includes Select2 but I did not test this. The error in particular I was looking at was $.fn.select2.defaults is not defined. (everything before "defaults" is defined). At least when in Common.js. In the console it appears to be defined.

I did not find CTA on the incompatible plugin list.
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+plugins+incompatible+with+CiviCRM

Does it need to be added? is there a known work-around?
Can someone point me to a model for resolving this conflict?

civicrm 4.5.8
WP 4.2.2
CTA 2.3.6

Comment: Just confirming:  is this the plugin:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/cta/  ?  We have used this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/call-to-action-widget/ when all we need is a widget and it has worked well wth CiviCRM

Comment: that's the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Select2 which we have [worked around](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16154) as of CiviCRM v4.6.0.

Comment: I confirmed that replacing the select2.min.js with the patched version does resolve the conflict on civicrm 4.5

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/colemanw/select2/09a6e7bb1f435c94869ad9e008c70f37fe60297d/select2.min.js